# Error in installing setup.py for twisted for django channels

Tags: visual-studio, django-channels

Error log that i am getting in vscode bash terminal

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\users\flowers\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\flowers\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
    raiser.c
    c:\users\flowers\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(206): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No
such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\flowers\appdata\local\programs\python\py
 tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Flowers\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zc2kyt8z\\twi
wers\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zc2kyt8z\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"
('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install -
record-m_o3jpo7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-heade
n\python38\Include\twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Before this error i was getting error saying you need to install `visual c++ 14.0 build tools` something and i then followed the link from suggestion and downloaded vs build tools and separately download and installed vsredit 2019 but now i am getting this error please help me i dont know what to do i just want to use django channels in my project....

I have tried installing channels using build tools i installed but its still not working the packages also had windows universal cdr(something like this) SDK .
I am using windows 7 64bit

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. if you resolved your issue can you suggest the best way to do

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

Download the right whl package for you python version(if you have trouble knowing what version of python you have, just lunch the interpreter ), in my case it was python 3.6 32 bit

use pip to install the package, assuming that the file is in downloads folder :
python -m pip install C:\Users%USER%\Downloads\Twisted-17.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

You can then try to install channels again usng pip